# Как запомнить и увеличить значение переменной при клике на button?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть n-ое число button'ов, создаваемых по циклу.
Там же им присваивается id и функция setClass(id). Эта функция меняет цвет этой кнопки несколько раз:

```
/* Цикл создающий таблицу из буттонов */
button.setAttribute("id", id);
button.setAttribute("onclick", "setColorClass('"+id+"')");

function setColorClass(id)
    {
      var elem = document.getElementById(id);
      if (elem.className == "firstClass")
      {
        elem.setAttribute("class", "SecondClass");
      }
      else if (elem.className == "SecondClass")
      {
        elem.setAttribute("class", "ThirdClass");
      } etc...
```

Мне нужно: чтобы при клике на одну кнопку ей присваивался атрибут с порядковым номером. При клике на какую-то другую кнопку: следующий номер и так далее. Нельзя чтобы при клике на одну и тужу кнопку номера перебирались. Одна кнопка - одна и та же цифра.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Создайте глобальную переменную, например `var i = 1`. При клике на кнопку проверяете есть ли ваш атрибут у элемента, если его нет, то создаете его со значением `i`, после прибавляете к `i` единицу(`i++`).

Comment: не совсем понятно, что кому должно присваивать?

Comment: @C.Raf.T элементу button атрибут number: `elem.setAttribute("number", number)`

Answer (score 1):

Ну если я правильно понял:

```js
var classArray = ["firstClass", "SecondClass", "ThirdClass", "firstClass", "SecondClass", "ThirdClass"];
var xx = document.getElementById("xxx");

function setColorClass(id) {
  let elem = document.getElementById(id);
  if (!elem.hasAttribute("class")) {
    elem.setAttribute("class", classArray[0]);
    classArray.shift();
    let num = 6 - classArray.length;
    elem.setAttribute("number", num);
    elem.innerHTML = num;
  }
}
for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
  let btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
  btn.setAttribute("id", i);
  btn.setAttribute("onclick", "setColorClass('" + i + "')");
  xx.appendChild(btn);

}
```

```css
button {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  color: #fff;
}
.firstClass {
  background: red;
}
.SecondClass {
  background: green;
}
.ThirdClass {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="xxx"></div>
```